# NSDate processing very CPU intensive

Tags: ios, objective-c, optimization, nsdate

I have a method in my code for processing a string that needs to be transformed in a NSDate. 
This method is called hundreds on times a second, and apparently is very inefficient. 
How can it be improved as much as possible?

```
- (NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

    NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

    if (date == nil) {
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
        date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    }
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number one thing you can do is *don't create that formatter instance each call*!

Creating formatters are very expensive. From Apple's "Data Formatting Guide":

> Creating a date formatter is not a cheap operation. If you are likely to use a formatter frequently, it is typically more efficient to cache a single instance than to create and dispose of multiple instances.

You can do this with a `static` var or with properties and the lazy load pattern. For example, using `static`:

```
-(NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString{
  static NSDateFormatter *formatterWithZone = nil;
  static NSDateFormatter *formatterWithoutZone = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    formatterWithZone = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatterWithZone setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    [formatterWithZone setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    formatterWithoutZone setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
  });

  NSDate *date = [formatterWithZone dateFromString:dateString];
  //...
  date = [formatterWithoutZone dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Or, if you're going to use the formatter elsewhere, put it in a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDateFormatter *formatterWithZone;
@property (nonatomic) NSDateFormatter *formatterWithoutZone;
//...

-(NSDateFormatter *)formatterWithZone{
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _formatterWithZone = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [_formatterWithZone setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    [_formatterWithZone setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
  });
  return _formatterWithZone;
}

-(NSDateFormatter *)formatterWithoutZone{
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _formatterWithoutZone = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [_formatterWithoutZone setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
  });
  return _formatterWithoutZone;
}

-(NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString{
  NSDate* date = [[self formatterWithZone] dateFromString:dateString];
  //...
  date = [[self formatterWithoutZone] dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

***UPDATE:***
Also check out (and upvote) [mrueg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166198/mrueg) comment below about `NSCalendar -currentCalendar` being expensive. Both the above techniques would work to cache an `NSCalendar` instance as well.

Comment: This is called 2 times per class instance. Which will mean I am still creating a forrmatter per class instance.(but there are a lot of instances). Would it be better if I create it in a class method?

Comment: You should do the same thing for each formatter. Either have two `static` vars that hold each of the different formatters (`formatterWithTimeZone` and `formatterWithoutTimeZone`, for example) or have two properties, one for each formatter. That way you never have to create either more than once.

Comment: Updated examples to cover this.

Comment: A note related to slow NSDate processing in general: `NSCalendar` objects are also slow, and `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` creates a new one on every call, so using the `static` trick is advisable for `NSCalendar` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Date formatters are very expensive to create (and to change the format of).

Make two `static` date formatter variables, one for each format, and use them instead of creating new formatters each time.

Create the formatters inside a dispatch_once block.